# How to import XML in postgresql 9.5

Tags: xml, postgresql, import

I've created a table with the following command:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(xmldata xml);
```

A file containing data is on my desktop. How would I import this file into my table?

Is there an existing utility, like SQLLoader in Oracle that does this?

Comment: if you have one column one row one xml value - use copy/paste. `insert into mytable select 'XML_CONTENTS';`

Comment: no my file is large file

Comment: so then? how it is organized?.. one xml value? CSV?

Answer (score 0):

consider using `COPY`, Eg:

```
a=# \! cat xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<greeting>Hello, world!</greeting>
a=# copy mytable from 'xml' ;
COPY 2
a=# select * from mytable ;
              xmldata
------------------------------------

 <greeting>Hello, world!</greeting>
(2 rows)
```

Comment: my file is large file